# What would be the best way of checking whether a string contains XML tags?

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I know that the following would find potential tags, but is there a better way to check if a string contains XML tags to prevent exceptions when reading/writing the string between XML files?

```
    string testWord = "test<a>";
    bool foundTag = Regex.IsMatch(testWord, @"^*<*>*$"));
```

Comment: Is this part of some parsing scheme?  Why not use classes designed for reading XML, such as `XmlDocument`?

Comment: Explain your question better. Is `testWord` a variable you're going to insert in an XML document, or do you want to extract an XML document from a random string, in this case `testWord`?

Comment: The string is going to be written to an XML file as an attribute. To prevent a misread of the file I'm trying to prevent that string containing a tag which could start or finish with an existing element or attribute's value.

Comment: Then you're asking the wrong question. The right question is: _"How do I properly escape a string so it can be inserted in an XML document"_, to which the answer is: you don't have to, since the [`XmlElement.InnerText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext.aspx) automatically escapes its input. If you're not using [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) or another library to write XML, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use another Regex for that

```
Regex.IsMatch(testWord, @"<.+?>");
```

However, even if it does match, there is no guarantee that your file actually *is* an xml file, as the regex could also match strings like `"<<a>"` which is invalid, or `"a <= b >= c"` which is obviously *not* xml.

You should consider using the [XmlDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) instead.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    xmlDoc.Load(testWord);
}
catch
{
    // not an xml
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you [`HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) the string before sending it via XML? This way you can avoid [difficulties with Regex parsing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).